# timing issue? or code structure?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, timing

I have the following code snippet...

```
$scope.submitForm = function(){ // called when form button clicked.
    if( $scope.formStatus.disabled || $scope.validationForm.$invalid ){ return; } // Doesn't allow multiple button clicking when button is in disabled state.
    submitFormForValidation();
  };
```

Every once in a great while, so great that I have only seen this happen once but have heard of it happen in the wild three times, the code above will execute the submitFormForValidation() function even though the form itself is invalid.

I am using Angularjs 1.3.0.beta-8.

Normally, the form will not submit when there is no value in any required input. If I enter a value, then delete it, the form will submit (but like I said very rarely, I have had no luck in recreating the issue, unless I hard code a setTimeout and pretend, this seams to recreate the issue.

I thought that perhaps it was due to the way I had structured the code, but as I think about it perhaps Angular/browser was bogged down for just enough time where the form was still valid from entering an input, and did not update the $invalid property until after the submitForm function had run. Thus, the form was tricked into still being valid.

Since I have had difficulty in witnessing this in the wild as it is so rare, I am assuming it is due to Angularjs not updating the form validation, which will then never exit the function and will run submitFormForValidation();

Here are my questions...

1. Is there anything incorrect with the way the code was written?
2. Is the version of Angularjs that I am using slower with the digest cycle or whatever runs form validation changes?
3. Would upgrading to Angularjs 1.3+ (any stable branch) give more consistent speed in change detection?

Again, this code works 4.0 for about 99% of the time. However, I do need 100% of the time.

I would also like to understand why this is happening as I consider setting a setTimeout() is more of a bandaid fix, which could still potentially fail if the timeout was not long enough.

**UPDATE**
If I may add...

User fills two inputs, FORM is VALID and can be submitted.

When it breaks,

User fills two inputs, then deletes one until empty. FORM is still VALID as far as Angular is concerned so the function does not return and thus fires the submitFormForValidation() function.

I have finally recreated this, but only once after hours. In the console, when looking at the form and inputs in the console, I can see that ng-valid and ng-invalid do get set for one of the inputs only, but the other input changes nothing. It's like it lost connection with Angular.

So the form will submit and behave as coded but only depending on whether the working input is valid, the broken input does not matter.

I have witnessed this happen with both inputs, so it's not specific to the input.

Comment: JS is single threaded, so for this code the `submitFormForValidation` call will be triggered for the consistent known state of the check before it. As soon as you don't do any async operations between data retrieval and sending it - I'd say it's not possible.

Comment: not enough code to sample here; in a shot in the dark.. take a look at `$rollbackViewValue` and see if the considerations involving its usage apply here..

Comment: Why not just disable your submit button unless status and validation are true?

Comment: @Cerad, I agree with that logic.. but the op stated **If I enter a value, then delete it, the form will submit** .. and he referenced timeout events, so I suspect there is no submit button to click in this application.

Comment: There is a button, and the button state would still allow submission because $scope.formname.$invalid, and $scope.formname.$valid will not be correct when in the broken condition.

Comment: When the form gets submitted when it shouldn't, are the values for the two inputs correct, just not the `.$invalid` state? Also, are you using `ng-model-options` to debounce the inputs?

Comment: According to the [AngularJS changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), there looks like there is a few fixes that might address your issue. It would be definitely worth updating to version 1.3.15 if possible and seeing if that resolves it.

Comment: Which issues are you suggesting? GregL.

Comment: When the form gets submitted in the invalid state, one of the inputs must have a value ( as that input still responds to the required requirement and does change class ng-valid to ng-invalid if there is no value ). The other input though does not change the ng-valid to ng-invalid or vice versa, the state would always just be ng-valid for the form (as long as the other input has a value). Once broken, it will remain in the state until the page is hard refreshed.  No, I am not using ng-model-options. I don't believe they are available in the current Angularjs I am using?